# Materialize dropdown in nav is behind elements

Tags: html, css, django, dropdown, materialize

I know this type of questions has been asked, I went over them but could not solve my problem.
In my page where I am using materialize, I have a nav bar with a dropdown button but whenever i open it, it would be behind another element. I am attaching a image of it
[I am attaching a image of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhzwx.png)

I have made a similar problem in fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/Illuminator0/pugy1j5b/10/

```
 <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a class='dropdown-button d' href='#' data-activates='dropdown2' data-hover="hover" data-alignment="left">Drop Me!</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>

<nav>
  <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class=" brand-logo center">
      <li>
        <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1' data-beloworigin="true">Drop Me!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
          I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Set ```nav``` position to ```relative``` and give it ```z-index``` of greater than your dropdown in your case set it to ```9999```.

Comment: tried it in fiddle, didn't work

Comment: Let me post an answer then!!

Comment: [Try This](https://jsfiddle.net/ex964mto/)

Comment: Sorry when i try to open it, it comes as blank( i.e. no code written )

This is a collaboration link,
https://jsfiddle.net/Illuminator0/pugy1j5b/10/#&togetherjs=87hcbwvzPP

try to make changes in it

Comment: Try this one instead [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ex964mto/1/)

Comment: No worries! Anytime 

Answer (score 0):

I used the above solution to solve the problem, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Illuminator0/hL6br23w/) of it

CSS code

```
.dropdown-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
  margin-left: 100%;
  position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution i just add **"z-index-1"** in **.card** class

```css
.dropdown-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
  margin-left: 100%;
  position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>




<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a class='dropdown-button d' href='#' data-activates='dropdown2' data-hover="hover" data-alignment="left">Drop Me!</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>

<nav>
  <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class=" brand-logo center">
      <li>
        <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1' data-beloworigin="true">Drop Me!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
          I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like the major problem is that the div with an id of `nav-wrapper` should be a class.** Your css looks for that class but there is none so never gets applied. Then in that class get rid of the `overflow: auto` and add `z-index: 1000`.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robulus/3fp7a6vL/5/).

And a snippet...

```css
.dropdown-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
  margin-left: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  /*overflow-y: auto;*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.card {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a class='dropdown-button d' href='#' data-activates='dropdown2' data-hover="hover" data-alignment="left">Drop Me!</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>

<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class=" brand-logo center">
      <li>
        <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1' data-beloworigin="true">Drop Me!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```